# Custom template for dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzine.js and i would like to style my own template.

My HTML code

```
        <div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
            <input type="hidden" name="file" multiple/>
        </div>

<section class="row" id="multiupload-expedition">
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
        <div class="dz-details">
            <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
            <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
            <img data-dz-thumbnail />
        </div>
        <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
        <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

JS code

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-awesome-dropzone", {
        maxFiles: 3,
        aceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx",
        url: "/innovate_git_ogmio/innovate/cz/expedition?do=fileUpload",
        previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#multiupload-expedition').innerHTML,
    });
```

But when i try to upload files, new elements are made inside div with "dropzone" class. 
Can someone please help me?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, do you want to create some custom template to be shown when you upload a file or what you're trying to do?